# How do I make SVG a responsive height?

Tags: css, svg

I've been trying to make a rectangle that's added in via :before, so the svg code is in an svg file and called through the styling.

The before container *is* the right height, but the svg is going to a larger height than the parent. Adjusting the viewbox height does change it, but it's not responsive.

Someone suggested adding the svg:not(root). That didn't help at all.

```
<svg class="svg-responsive" viewBox="0 0 100 100" 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" preserveAspectRatio="none" 
style="position: absolute;">
    <style>
    rect.shape{
        fill: transparent;
        stroke: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
        stroke-width: 0.25;
    }
    svg:not (:root ) {
        width:100%;
        height: auto;
    }
</style>
<rect class="shape" width="100%" height="100%"></rect>
```

I'm hoping to be able to use the same svg for multiple different lists that vary in height, and would like to avoid having to create different ones for each.

Answer (score 0):

Is your container `position: relative`? Absolutely positioned elements position themselves relative to the nearest relative parent.

If that doesn't work, post more of your code.

If you're just trying to put a stroke around the lists you might look into css's `border` property as it would be easier to deal with.

Comment: I wish borders were an option, because it'd definitely make life easier. I need the rectangle to be drawn in though, using stroke. Here's code to help demonstrate what my issue is https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qQeQMp

Comment: Are you saying you want to be to size the rectangle non-proportionally? e.g. your original rectangle is 5 x 10 and you want to be able to make it 5 x 20? Sorry I'm still having a hard time understanding what you're trying to accomplish. Could you clarify what you mean by "drawn in though, using stroke".

Comment: I'd like to make the SVG rect the same height as it's parent, which would vary in height based on how many list items there are